# "Invalid Equation" error when generating html & md reports with knitr

Tags: r, knitr, mathjax

I have equations in my Rmd report that display fine in preview within RStudio,

```
$$
\begin{align*}
\text{hwy}_i & \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu_i, \sigma_\epsilon) \\
\mu_i & = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \text{displ_mc}_i \\
\beta_0 & \sim \operatorname{Normal}(20, 5) \\
\beta_1 & \sim \operatorname{Normal}(-2.5, 1) \\
\sigma_\epsilon & \sim \operatorname{Exponential}(1)
\end{align*}
$$
```

[image]

... but when I knit my report in html or in md format I only see an "Invalid Equation" icon in the report

[image]

I'm not sure why, but it seems to be the line "\mu_i & = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \text{displ_mc}_i \" that is triggering the error. When I remove this line the report knits fine. But obviously I need that information in my report.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the `_` as `{\_}` worked in knitted report

```
$$
\begin{align*}
\mu_i & = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \text{displ}{\_}\text{mc}_i \\
\end{align*}
$$
```

[image]